# How to find max level in each path in a Oracle hierarchical SQL?

Tags: oracle, connect-by

I would like to know the way to find the max level number in Oracle hierarchical SQL within the given path.

For example : If connect by clause starts with root 1 having below relation .

```
parent_id node_id votes
 NULL    1        -
 1       2        10 
 2       3        12 
 3       4        11
 1       20        5
 20      30       20
 20      40        4
 40      50       22
```

Here first 3 records belongs to one path with max levle 3.
Next 2 records belong to another path with max level 2.
Last two record belongs to another path with max level 3.

I need output with these max level within the given distinct path and minimum votes:

```
parent_id  node_id LEVEL  MAX_LEVL  MIN_VOTE
   1       2         1        3        10
   2       3         2        3        10
   3       4         3        3        10
   1       20        1        2         5
   20      30        2        2         5
   1       20        1        3         4
   20      40        2        3         4 
   40      50        3        3         4 



     1
     |
--------------
|           |
2           20              
|           |
3     --------------
|     |             |
4     30            40
                    |
                   50
```

Thanks,
Guru

Comment: To make it clear, simplify the example using only `node_id` and `parent_id`. Your current example is confusing: node 1 has parent 2, but 1 is root node. How can a *root node have a parent*?

Comment: Modified. .Thanks

Comment: It would seem, that your understanding of "parent" is reversed in comparison to the common understanding. I.e. from your graph, the "1" would be "root", so would not have any parents (`parent_id` of node "1" would usually be `NULL`). It would be parent of "2" and "20" (so nodes with those ID-s would have `parent_id` set to "1"). As this is your DB and your application, you can name things as you wish, and maybe it does make perfect sense for your case, so I'm not judging. :)

Comment: Thanks Hilarion for your feedback. Can you help me to get the above output based on the graph. Updated the column names.

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated.. Thanks in advance...